# How create ContextMenu for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I am need create feature like in iOS "Photos" system app, when you are have a list of photos and use long press to image, this collection view with images exanded, all background is blurred and has appeared popover menu, how I can create it?
I am can detect long press on collection view and add some view behind, also I am try create blur effect but can't blur all behind particular cell.

This is image of this effect [effect inside system app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgJFK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screen shot shows a [context menu interaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction). Since this feature already exists at framework level, and since a collection view is ready to [implement it for you](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/3295917-collectionview), I suggest you just use it rather than trying to reinvent such a complicated thing for yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer was be more than enough). For examining this features I am use this article (https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-implement-uicontextmenuinteraction-in-swift-b4508a0f2917).

And I am have the next one question, if I am will tried create this menu using this way: Long press on cell, than above create visual effect with blur above tried create uiview with data from cell and simultishously create table view for context menu, with which underwater rocks I am faced? Apart from the position of elements on the screen.